# Array rotation(Juggling method) in python - List Index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, indexing, rotation

Array rotation can be done by slicing in python or even some other easier way too. But, I found a method in GFG - which has the following procedure to rotate an array:

Instead of moving one by one, divide the array into different sets where a number of sets are equal to GCD of n and d and move the elements within sets.
If GCD is 1, then, for example, array (n = 7 and d =2), then elements will be moved within one set only, we just start with temp = arr[0] and keep moving arr[I+d] to arr[I] and finally store temp at the right place.
Here is an example for n =12 and d = 3. GCD is 3 and

Let arr[] be {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}

a) Elements are first moved in first set –
arr[] after this step --> {4 2 3 7 5 6 10 8 9 1 11 12}

b)Then in second set.
arr[] after this step --> {4 5 3 7 8 6 10 11 9 1 2 12}

c)Finally in the third set.
arr[] after this step --> {4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3}

I tried to implement this method in python:

```
arr = [9,8,0,3,4,5,6,7,8]
d=3
for i in range(d):
    for j in range(i,len(arr),d):
        if j+1 == len(arr)-d+(i+1):
            break
        temp = arr[j]
        arr[j]=arr[j+d]
        arr[j+d] = temp
print(arr)
```

I don't know where I have gone wrong with the code. For this particular array as well as d value(rotation value) - I get the perfect output : [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 0]

But, when I give the value of d=2,
I get this error:

```
File ".\array_rotation.py", line 114, in <module>
    arr[j]=arr[j+d]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The same goes for different arrays too, I get a correct answer for the array according to the 'd' value.

The other array: arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], d=2 -> I get perfect answer: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2]
But with d=5 -> Again, I get list index out of range error.

I don't know where I have gone wrong - some test cases work and some do not.

Comment: I suspect this condition is not correct: `if j+1 == len(arr)-d+(i+1):`. BTW, the `+1` on both sides cancels out, so you can remove it.

Comment: Try changing `==` to `>=`. You should also be able to change the `range()` so you don't need this check.